# C# - Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Tags: c#

I am getting this error when I am trying to connect to a computer remotely using System.management:

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005 (E_ACCESSDENIED))

Here is my code:

```
try
        {
            ConnectionOptions options = new ConnectionOptions();
            options.Impersonation = System.Management.ImpersonationLevel.Impersonate;
            options.Authentication = AuthenticationLevel.Packet;
            options.Timeout = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 30);
            options.EnablePrivileges = true;
            options.Username = "\\" + textBox2.Text;
            options.Password = textBox3.Text;
            ManagementPath path = new ManagementPath(@"\\" + textBox1.Text + @"\root\cimv2");
            ManagementScope scope = new ManagementScope(path, options);
            scope.Connect();
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            return;
        }
```

Can someone explain why I get this error?

Comment: Tried run as admin?

Comment: Running as admin didn't work.

Comment: what do you want to do with above code?

Comment: I wan't to connect to a computer remotely.

Answer (score 0):

Given that your username provided is correct, exists and has the permissions to access the machine.

This line

```
options.Username = "\\" + textBox2.Text;
```

will lead to a username like `\administrator`, which is not a valid username. You need to define the domain, or the scope. So try using this:

```
options.Username = ".\\" + textBox2.Text;
```

That will define a local user (on the remote machine). When using a domain user, write the domain name in front of the backslash:

```
options.Username = "MyCorp\\" + textBox2.Text;
```

Comment: I'm still getting access denied.

Comment: So then your credentials seem to be invalid

Comment: Is it something to do with firewall?

Comment: I tried connecting to a virtual machine and I got The RPC server is unavailable. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800706BA).

Comment: Try to connect to that virtual machine using a more simple connection such as RDP (you need RDP allowed though). I am pretty sure you have a routing problem between your host and your virtual machine, they don't see each other in the same net.

Comment: If I type an incorrect password I get access denied. If they are correct I get The RPC Server is unavailable.

Comment: So then there's something wrong with your guest system. Check the services `services.msc` and see if the rpc-service is running. By default, it is disabled

Comment: Remote Procedure Call (RPC) is running but I had to start Remote Procedure Call (RPC) Locator.

Comment: No, it doesn't.

Comment: So then try to connect via RDP (activate RDP first on the guest machine)

Comment: How do I do that?

Comment: Do you have any server application running on your guest machine? Try to connect there, if this doesn't work, your problem is not the RPC.

Comment: Don't worry about it.